# Maxima and minima

Tags: calculus

RELATIVE MAXIMUM AND MINIMUM VALUES OF A FUNCTION.

A function $f(x)$ is said to have a relative maximum at $x = x_0$ if $f(x_0) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$ in some open interval containing $x_0$,that is, if the value of $f(x_0)$ is greater than or equal to the values of $f(x)$ at all nearby points.
The neighborhood is $0 <|x-c|< \delta$.

My question: Consider a function $f(x)=x$.  Consider two points, $x=1$ and $x=1.1$, we will get $f(1.1) \geq f(1)$ but again, $f(1.1) \geq f(1.2)$, and so on.  So which is the maxima of the function $f(x)=x$? Similar argument for the minima.

Do we have $n$ number of maxima and minima for any function?

Comment: To use $\TeX$, enclose it in dollar signs (single for inline, double for display). You need backslashes in commands like `\geq`, but not elsewhere, e.g. before `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion you seem to be making is not correct; just knowing that $f(1.1)>f(1)$, for example, does not tell you that $f(1.1)$ is a local maximum value. To show that $f(a)$ is a local maximum value, you'd have to prove that $f(x)\le f(a)$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$ sufficiently close to $a$. Here, you cannot do that; $f$ has no local minimum or maximum values by your implied argument.

Note that the definition you give is for *relative* maximum and minimum values. Whereas you seem to be referring to *global* maximum and minimum values in the sequel.

A *local maximum value* $f(x_0)$ is a the largest value the function attains in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Note, the definition said that $f(x_0)$ is greater than or equal to the values of $f(x)$ at all *nearby points* $x$.

A *global maximum  value* $f(x_0)$ must  satisfy $f(x_0)$ is greater than or equal to the values of $f(x)$ for *all* $x$.

There are similar definitions for local and global minimum values.

These concepts also take into account the domain of the function.

For instance, if you restrict $f(x)=x$ to have domain $[0,1.1]$, say, then $f(0)=0$ will be both a local and a global minimum value and $f(1.1)=1.1$ will be both a local and a global maximum value.  To be precise, we would say $f$ has both a local and global  maximum value of $f(1.1)=1.1$ over $[0,1.1]$; and, $f$ has both a local and a global minimum value of $f(0)=0$ over $[0,1.1]$.

If you consider $f(x)=x$ to have domain $\Bbb R$, as I assumed in the first paragraph, then it would have no local or global maximum  values by your observations. It would also have no local or global minimum values.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, but my confusion persists, for a real line, any function will have n number of points on it so we will have n number of intervals enclosing each of the n points and sufficiently close to each of the n points, and for each of these n intervals we will have one value greater than another value, so do we arrive at the conclusion that we have n maxima and minima?

Comment: @Vikram No. You have to $fix$ the interval you are working over at the outset. Say we consider $[0,10]$. Now take a point $a$ in this interval. $f(a)$ will be a local maximum value if and only if there is a  (small) interval around $a$ such that the values of $f$ for $every$ point in that interval are at most $f(a)$. Note that this includes points on "both sides" of $a$. If you look at the graph of the function, it would have a "hump" at $(a,f(a))$.

Comment: @Vikram It is true that $f(x)=x$ has the maximum value $1$ over $[0,1]$ and has the maximum value 2 over $[0,2]$, etc... But notice I said "maximum value over $[0,1]$, maximum value over $[0,2]$, etc...". These different maximum values are referring to $different$ intervals.  $f(1)=1$ is $not$ a maximum value over $[0,2]$ (look at the graph), but is is a maximum value over the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanx David, I think you clarified my doubt, now I will solve some problems to check my understanding, but I feel your explanation does fill the gaps in my understanding about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = x$ has no absolute or relative maxima/minima.  No matter what value you give me for the relative maxima (respectively, minima), I can find a larger value (respectively, smaller value) *nearby* obtained by the function.

To answer the second part, yes you can find a function which has any number of prescribed maxima/minima.  You can draw a sawtooth function with as many "high points" or "low points" as you wish, for example.